# How to retrieve field value from response body after making post request?

Tags: json, parsing, selenium-webdriver

I have a post request.

```
  @Test
    public <JSONObject> void postCrawlTaskOnPortal() throws IOException {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\n  \"AppVersion\": \"Lorem Ut est\",\n  \"DeviceId\": \"amet\",\n  \"DeviceType\": \"web\",\n  \"Password\": \"\",\n  \"UserName\": \"\" \n}\n\n\n");
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("")
                .method("POST", body)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Accept", "*/*")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "LDc0LDE0MSwxMjMsODMsOCw5LDEwLDExLDE0LDE1LDE3LDE4LDE5LDIwLDIxLDY1LDY4LDcxLDI3LDEyMCwxMjYsMTIyLDQsMjIsMjMsMjQsMjYsMjgsMjksMzEsMzIsMzMsMzQsMzUsMzYsMzcsMzgsNDEsNDUsNDYsNDksNTMsNTQsNTUsNTYsNTcsNTgsNjIsNjYsNjcsNjksNzIsNzMsNzUsNzYsNTEsMjUsNDMsNzAsMzksNTAsNDgsNDcsNDAsNDQsOTQsOTIsMTQyLDg2LDEwOCwxMDEsMTExLDExNCwxMzAsOTksOTUsMTAyLDEwNiwxMDksOTgsOTMsODUsMTIxLDEyNywxMDQsMTM0LDEwMCwxMDddLFwiQm9pbGVySWRzXCI6bnVsbCxcIkVtcGxveWVlSXNHcm91cEJvaWxlcnNcIjpmYWxzZX0ifQ.TeKe4bCltGUotI6NinH3qx5xy3CFHAhabAGX9v53qps")
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I get a response -

```
{"AccessToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2NzY5ODEyNTMsInNlc3Npb24iOiJ7XCJTSURcIjpcIjk5ZDVlZjM3LWMyZTMtNGE5ZC05ZjQyLWE5N2YyYzRhZGZlOVwiLFwiVXNlclVVSURcIjpcImQzYTBhNDcyLTIwMzQtNDBkYy05ZDJlLWJjNmQ2OWViMmM5OFwiLFwiRW1wbGdnJFl0_obiPtb9pCmRKHJbf2BkD7PWBhHORgsOgb9Gs","UserUUID":"d3a0a472-2034-40dc-9d2e-bc6d69eb2c98","Session":{"SID":"99d5ef37-c2e3-4a9d-9f42-a97f2c4adfe9","EmployeeUUID":"ab94be90-02b9-41ba-809b-f7a573dc70c6","AppVersion":"Lorem Ut est","DeviceType":"web","DeviceId":"amet","FullName":"User","PermissionsHash":""":[1,137,97,105,45,46,49,53,54,55,56,57,58,62,66,67,69,72,73,75,76,51,25,43,70,39,50,48,47,40,44,94,92,142,86,108,101,111,114,130,99,95,102,106,109,98,93,85,121,127,104,134,100,107],"BoilerIds":null,"":false}}
```

After that I need to get value of field `AuthorizationToken` and save it to a variable.
I've used Jsoup but not successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `JSONObject` class to parse the JSON response and retrieve the `AuthorizationToken` value.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

String authorizationToken = jsonObject.getString("AuthorizationToken");
```